# Inspinia side navigation

Tags: inspinia

Recently I have bought [INSPINIA - Responsive Admin Theme](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/inspinia-responsive-admin-theme-WB0R5L90S), but I found I can't even get the same output for the side navigation... Anyone could help? Please...

The is the expected result...

[image]

I have no idea what else I miss out, until the whole side navigation bar got it hide once I trigger the button.

[image]

And some times I got the worst if I refresh the page...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<body class=" mini-navbar">
```

This is used for minibar